# Methods of labeling human muscles on tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision

I want to be able to label all of the muscles on an athletes body. I got a lot of the images that the athletes are almost in the same body pose but the issue that I am running into is that drawing a box around them makes them inaccurate as it ends up overlapping other muscles. Drawing exact lines around them is a bit difficult as they are a lot of smaller muscles and creates inconsistently over 20-30images. I was wondering if there is a way to feed in a human anatomy and then have tensorflow go in and label all of the muscles in given pictures.

Or I was wondering if you all had a different idea on approach this problem that I'm running into.

*I don't have anybody else to ask and I've been researching this for awhile so if I missed or overlooked something please forgive me*

Answer (score 0):

The way i see is you need to combine with some prepossessing steps to normalize your target object in the image such as:

1. identify the human,
2. identify the pose or skeleton (which nowadays many open-source  such as openpose-plus),
3. the pose estimation results can label the limbs, or part of the body from which you can do something either by hand-crafted image processing or other segmentation model.